# program which will be able to find "val" in array V and other stuffs

Tags: c

I want to write a short program which be able to find "val" in array V, remove "val" from V if it exists, or, insert "Val" in V if not and of course the ascending order of V must be preserved

Where are the errors? it drives me crazy....
I am definitely a big beginner

The problem isn't at the first

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int V[100];
        int i=0, n, c, j, val, Go=0, k;    
        printf("Size");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &V[i]) ;
        }

        for ( i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for ( j=0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if ( V[j] > V[i] )
                {
                    c = V[i];
                    V[i] = V[j];            //We just Reordered V 
                    V[j] = c;
                }
            }
        }    
    
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf(" %d ", V[i]);
        }
    
            printf ("\n");
            printf ("\n Enter the value that you want ");
            scanf("%d", &val);
    
             while ( i< n && Go == 0)             //Here begin problems ....
            {
                if ( val > V[i] )
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Go =1 ;
                }
            }
    
            if ( Go == 1 )
            {
    
                if ( V[i] == val )                      //We delete Val
                {
    
                    for ( k = i; k<n; k++)
                    {
                        V[k] = V[k+1] ;
                    }
                    n = n-1;
                }
        
                else                                                //i.e val < V[i]
                {
                    for ( k=n; k>=i; k-- )            // We add Val if doesn't exist
                    {
                        V[k+1] = V[k] ;
                    }
    
                    V[i] = val ;
                    n = n+1;    
                }   
            }
    
            else
            {
                n = n+1;
                V[n] = V[n+1];
            }      
    
            for ( i =0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf ("%d \t", V[i]) ;
            }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code.

You use `i` whithout reinitialize it after using it in the for loop to print array. So you need set `i=0;` after for loop like below:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
      printf(" %d ", V[i]);
}
    
printf ("\n");

printf ("\n Enter the value that you want ");
scanf("%d", &val);

i=0;   // ********add this line**********
while ( i< n && Go == 0)             //Here begin problems ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Because of this I stayed awake until 2 a.m.

Comment: No need to thank you. Just accept answer if it is right. You say was awake until 2 a.m. , let me welcome you to programmers world.